# How to join tables in Matlab (2018) by matching time intervals?

Tags: matlab, timestamp, time-series, data-mining, matlab-table

I have two tables A and B. I want to join them based on their validity time intervals.

A has product quality (irregular times) and B has hourly settings during the production period. I need to create a table like C that includes the parameters p1 and p2 for all A's RefDates that fall in the time range of B's ValidFrom ValidTo.

```
A
RefDate                 result
'11-Oct-2017 00:14:00'  17
'11-Oct-2017 00:14:00'  19
'11-Oct-2017 00:20:00'  5
'11-Oct-2017 01:30:00'  25
'11-Oct-2017 01:30:00'  18
'11-Oct-2017 03:03:00'  28


B
ValidFrom               ValidTo                 p1  p2
'11-Oct-2017 00:13:00'  '11-Oct-2017 01:12:59'  2   1
'11-Oct-2017 01:13:00'  '11-Oct-2017 02:12:59'  3   1
'11-Oct-2017 02:13:00'  '11-Oct-2017 03:12:59'  4   5
'11-Oct-2017 03:13:00'  '11-Oct-2017 04:12:59'  6   1
'11-Oct-2017 04:13:00'  '11-Oct-2017 05:12:59'  7   9
```

I need to get something like this.

```
C
RefDate                 res p1  p2
'11-Oct-2017 00:14:00'  17  2   1
'11-Oct-2017 00:14:00'  19  2   1
'11-Oct-2017 00:20:00'  5   2   1
'11-Oct-2017 01:30:00'  25  3   1
'11-Oct-2017 01:30:00'  18  3   1
'11-Oct-2017 03:03:00'  28  4   5
```

I know how to do this in SQL and I think I have figured out how to do this row by row in MatLab but this is horribly slow. The data set is rather large. I just assume there must be a more elegant way that I just couldn't find.

Something that caused many of my approaches to fail is that the RefDate column is not unique.

edit: 
the real tables have thousands of rows and hundreds of variables.

```
C (in reality)
RefDate                 res res2 ... res200 p1  p2 ... p1000
11-Oct-2017 00:14:00    17                  2   1
11-Oct-2017 00:14:00    19                  2   1
11-Oct-2017 00:20:00    5                   2   1
11-Oct-2017 01:30:00    25                  3   1
11-Oct-2017 01:30:00    18                  3   1
11-Oct-2017 03:03:00    28                  4   5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can actually be done in a single line of code. Assuming your `ValidTo` value always ends immediately before the `ValidFrom` in the next row (which it does in your example), you only need to use your `ValidFrom` values. First, convert those and your `RefDate` values to serial date numbers using [`datenum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html). Then use the [`discretize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/discretize.html) function to bin the `RefDate` values using the `ValidFrom` values as the edges, which will give you the row index in `B` that contains each time in `A`. Then use that index to extract the `p1` and `p2` values and append them to `A`:

```
>> C = [A B(discretize(datenum(A.RefDate), datenum(B.ValidFrom)), 3:end)]

C = 

           RefDate            result    p1    p2
    ______________________    ______    __    __

    '11-Oct-2017 00:14:00'    17        2     1 
    '11-Oct-2017 00:14:00'    19        2     1 
    '11-Oct-2017 00:20:00'     5        2     1 
    '11-Oct-2017 01:30:00'    25        3     1 
    '11-Oct-2017 01:30:00'    18        3     1 
    '11-Oct-2017 03:03:00'    28        4     5
```

The above solution should work for any number of columns `pN` in `B`.

If there are any times in `A` that don't fall in any of the ranges in `B`, you will have to break the solution into multiple lines so you can check whether or not the index returned from `discretize` contains `NaN` values. Assuming you want to exclude those rows from `C`, this would be the new solution:

```
index = discretize(datenum(A.RefDate), datenum(B.ValidFrom));
C = [A(~isnan(index), :) B(index(~isnan(index)), 3:end)];
```

Comment: the above (nice) code fails if a `RefDate` in `A` does not find a match in `B`.

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer. I didn't even think of `datenum`. This worked as soon as I figured out the NaN problem. Which I see now has been addressed by you as well. Your fix is way more elegant than the one I came up with.

Answer (score 2):

The following code does exactly what you are asking for:

```
% convert to datetime
A.RefDate = datetime(A.RefDate);
B.ValidFrom = datetime(B.ValidFrom);
B.ValidTo = datetime(B.ValidTo);

% for each row in A, find the matching row in B
i = cellfun(@find, arrayfun(@(x) (x >= B.ValidFrom) & (x <= B.ValidTo), A.RefDate, 'UniformOutput', false), 'UniformOutput', false);

% find rows in A that where not matched
j = cellfun(@isempty, i, 'UniformOutput', false);

% build the result
C = [B(cell2mat(i),:) A(~cell2mat(j),:)];

% display output
C
```

Comment: Thank you. That has some aspects in it to improve my current approach but there are hundreds of the p1,p2 columns so an individual approach would not work.

Comment: hopefully this can help (R2018b): [https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/outerjoin.html](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/outerjoin.html)

Comment: I have looked at the documentation. But I haven't found something that works like the ON in SQL. In SQL I can specify the keys in more detail. I am looking for something like that. It might be that this doesn't exist in Matlab.

Comment: @Schae: I see your point. Even I did not found a 'native' solution fot joining two tables, I updated my code to solve your problem in a more general fashion: now the only mandatory columns are `A.RefDate`, `B.ValidFrom`, and `B.ValidTo`.